# How to make Postman/Newman to fail a test after certain time has passed?

Tags: jenkins, postman, newman

So, in my collection I have about ten requests, with the last two being:

```
/Wait 10 seconds

/Check Complete
```

The first makes a call to the postman's echo (delay by 10 seconds) and the second is the call to my system to check for the status complete. Now, if status is unavailable I wait another 10s:

```
postman.setNextRequest("Wait 10 seconds");
```

The complete status on my system can appear in a minute or so. Now, as one can see - it is an infinite loop if something goes wrong with the system and status is never complete. Is there a way in postman/newman test to fail a test if it has been going for more than 2 minutes, for example.

Additionally, this will be executed in jenkins with command line, so I am not really looking into postman settings or delays between requests in the runner.

Comment: Why don't you use a global counter variable of retries, and after 6 retries you fail the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have a look to newman options here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options. The interesting option is 
--timeout-request : it will surely fulfill your need. 
In Postman itself, you may test the responseTime. I recall that there is a snippet, on the right part, which looks like this:

```
tests["Response time is less than 200ms"] = responseTime < 200;
```

and which could help you as the test fails if response does not occur within the requested time.

Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using Jenkins pipeline you can use the timeout [step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit) to cause long running jobs to result in failure, here's on for 2 mins.

```
timeout(120) {
  node {
    sh 'newman command'
  }
}
```

Check out the "[Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/31/pipeline-snippetizer/)" editor in Jenkins to generated your code block and look for other useful functions.

Comment: Interesting approach, but a timeout will kill an entire pipeline, won't it? If one stage/step timeouts, the whole thing is killed.

Comment: Correct, what is your desired output of a failed test? Are you looking to continue to the other tests or exit ?

Comment: correct, I have more tests in the pipe, so just because the one in context has failed - I do not want to abort all other stuff.